# In Perl, how can I replace sequences of duplicates with one element in an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, duplicates

I have a string that I read in like:

```
a+c+c+b+v+f+d+d+d+c
```

I need to write the program so it splits at the `+` then deletes the duplicates so the output is:

```
acbvfdc
```

I've tried `tr///cs;` but I guess I'm not using it right?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @strings = qw(
    a+c+c+b+v+f+d+d+d+c
    alpha+bravo+bravo+bravo+charlie+delta+delta+delta+echo+delta
    foo+food
    bark+ark
);

for my $s (@strings) {
    # Thanks @ikegami
    $s =~ s/ (?<![^+]) ([^+]+) \K (?: [+] \1 )+ (?![^+]) //gx;
    print "$s\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a+c+b+v+f+d+c
alpha+bravo+charlie+delta+echo+delta
foo+food
bark+ark
```

Now, you can split the string and have no sequences of duplicates using `split /[+]/, $s` because the first argument of [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a **pattern**.

Comment: I put this into my code (which I can't figure out how to post here) and it deleted the duplicates but now when I try to split at the "+" it tells me that "Quantifier follows nothing in the regex" and stops the program from running.

Comment: `+` is special in a regex pattern. You either have to escape it, or put it in a character class (as I did in my `s///` above).

Comment: That will fail for `foo+food` and for `bark+ark`.

Comment: Yes, realised that and withdrew that comment. Off to delete my own answer too.

Comment: Quick fix: `s/ (?<![^+]) ([^+]+) \K (?: [+] \1 )+ (?![^+]) //gx;` Also got rid of `$1` in replacement expression by using `\K`.

Answer (score 1):

Note to any who reads: this does not address the OP's question directly, though in my defense the question was worded ambiguously. :-) Still, it answers an interpretation of the question that others might have, so I'll leave it as-is.

Does order matter? If not, you can always try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'a+c+c+b+v+f+d+d+d+c';

# Extract unique 'words'
my @words = keys %{{map {$_ => 1} split /\+/, $string}};

print "$_\n" for @words;
```

Better yet, use List::MoreUtils from CPAN (which *does* preserve the order):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my $string = 'a+c+c+b+v+f+d+d+d+c';

# Extract unique 'words'
my @words = uniq split /\+/, $string;

print "$_\n" for @words;
```

Comment: This splits it but I need it to only delete the duplicates when they come one after the other.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't quite sure based on your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $s="a+c+c+b+v+f+d+d+d+c";
$s =~ tr/+//d;
$s =~ tr/\0-\xff/\0-\xff/s;
print "$s\n"; # => acbvfdc
```

Comment: That does work in this special case, but it is not generalizable to the case where the elements are anything other than individual characters and/or the elements contain anything outsize of the `a-z` range.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Well, the OP certainly implied that the case in question was individual characters, and that he would be interested in a tr// solution.  One can generalize to ascii instead of a-z with `$s=~tr/\0-\xff/\0-\xff/s;`.